# ACPI BIOS error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bios, acpi

I've had problems with my Laptop since a while now, I cant explain it that good but i can try. There a multiple problems, the first occurs when booting my Laptop (ROG Strix G513RW_G513RW 1.0), when starting my Laptop it often happens that the screen doesnt show the boot logo/animation nor the sound and it may boot but the display stays black. Another weird thing that happens is that while using my Laptop it freezes but it somehow unfreezes if i move the laptops lid a bit. It can also happen that it freezes completely then i have to reboot.

So i've come to the idea to run logwatch in Linux Mint and it gave me this Section, which i think could relate to my problems:

```
--------------------- Kernel Begin ------------------------ 

 WARNING:  Kernel Errors Present
    ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not ...:  2 Time(s)
    ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure c ...:  1 Time(s)
    ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXIS ...:  1 Time(s)
    ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, D ...:  2 Time(s)
    WARNING: CPU: 11 PID: 319 at drivers/gpu/drm/amd ...:  1 Time(s)
    WARNING: CPU: 13 PID: 1570 at drivers/gpu/drm/am ...:  1 Time(s)
    WARNING: See https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/ ...:  1 Time(s)
 
 ---------------------- Kernel End -------------------------
```

here you can download the full kernel logwatch file: [Download](https://s3.filebin.net/filebin/c91b344f5cb900b4f5bdf8fe4efad1467cc2f6c0532111d12aa78739dabf49a2/88e6b3a28efb310b845750de2735e61fd21197c4048f090b1ca085f2949102d2?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=7pMj6hGeoKewqmMQILjm%2F20240204%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240204T142423Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-cache-control=max-age%3D300&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22journalctllog.txt%22&response-content-type=text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&X-Amz-Signature=508da62b2b9c8a382173f759e4881c463345a198dd0682c84f68dbb3267e2ea1)

If you need more Information provided like other logfiles and so on, please ask.

Comment: sounds like a faulty cable that runs through the lid hinge